# How can I find the position of a corner of a transformed sprite in SFML?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

I need help with calculating the end points of a stick (a sprite) in my stick game.

First, I set up it's position by some coordinate (x,y) after that I rotate it by theta degrees.

I know the width and height (427, 17), but I can't figure out how to calculate it's end points after the rotation (I need them for intersect detection algorithm).

Moreover, I can't figure out how to detect when I clicked on it with the mouse, because `getGlobalbounds.contains(mouse)` gives me its bounding box, but I want to detect that I was clicked exactly on the entity..

[image: this is the stick]

Answer (score 1):

This is why SFML provides the sf::Transform and sf::Transform classes. Given a sprite with width and height [32, 32], we know that SFML treats the origin as the upper left corner. When you set a position for a sprite, the internal transform is modified and will be applied when you draw the sprite.

The position of that upper left corder (unless you changed the origin) is the position you get when you call getPosition() on the sprite. In the local coordinates of the sprite itself, untransformed, the position of that vertex is [0, 0]. Now if you want to get the position of the upper right corner, [32, 0], you can use the sprites internal transform and transform a vector with this position.

```
sprite.getTransform().transformPoint(32, 0); // Get position of upper right corner
sprite.getTransform().transformPoint(32, 32); // get position of lower right corner
sprite.getTransform().transformPoint(32, 32); // get position of lower left corner
```

Now keep in mind that this is limited to this case. If you change the origin of the sprite, the math changes. I would suggest that you familiarize yourself with linear algebra and linear transformations, to help you understand and solve geometric problems in a new way.

And for finding if a vector is contained by the sprite, not by the bounding box, you can use the axis aligned local bounding box. Take the inverse transform of the sprite and use it to transform the vector you want to test.

```
sf::Vector2f localPosition = sprite.getInverseTransform().transformPoint(somePosition);
if (sprite.getLocalBounds().contains(localPosition)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the centre point of the stick. You are rotating one end around the centre by x radians/degrees, and the other end also by the same amount, plus or minus 180 degrees / pi radians. So if you always treat your stick's centre as its actual position, it is easy enough to use matrices or even basic trigometry (which matrices rely on) to rotate the two ends of the stick. Of course, this assumes you will always be rotating a stick by its centre, but it gives you a basis for considering the rotation of the stick from any point. It should be clear that the degree by which each end rotates, is directly proportional to how close you are from either end, e.g. when we rotate around centre, we are splitting the rotation 50-50 for each end of the stick, hence they experience equal rotation.

You will also want to look into either [PPCD](https://www.gamedev.net/resources/_/technical/game-programming/intelligent-2d-collision-and-pixel-perfect-precision-r3311), or [some numerical / geometric method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274712/calculate-on-which-side-of-a-straight-line-is-a-given-point-located) of determining whether the mouse click falls within the stick's rotated bounds.